# How can I optimize this little piece of code

Tags: java

I started a java course and i was given an assignment to check if two triangles are congruent based on the values of their vertices provided by a user.
I am not allowed to add in any packages(except the one i did) nor am i allowed to use any loops.
It works fine but is there a shorter more effecient solution?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Congruent
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("We will now calculate if two triangles are 
        congruent.");

        System.out.println("Enter the vertices values of the first triangle.");
        System.out.println("Please enter x1:");
        float x11 = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter y1:");
        float y11 = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter x2:");
        float x12 = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter y2:");
        float y12 = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter x3:");
        float x13 = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter y3:");
        float y13 = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the vertices values of the second triangle.");
        System.out.println("Please enter x1:");
        float x21 = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter y1:");
        float y21 = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter x2:");
        float x22 = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter y2:");
        float y22 = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter x3:");
        float x23 = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter y3:");
        float y23 = scan.nextInt();
        //calculating distances between the vertices of the first triangle and 
        placing them in variables
        double a1 = Math.sqrt((Math.pow((x11 - x12), 2)) + (Math.pow((y11 - 
        y12), 2)));
        double b1 = Math.sqrt((Math.pow((x12 - x13), 2)) + (Math.pow((y12 - 
        y13), 2)));
        double c1 = Math.sqrt((Math.pow((x13 - x11), 2)) + (Math.pow((y13 - 
        y11), 2)));
        //calculating distances between the vertices of the second triangle and 
        placing them in variables
        double a2 = Math.sqrt((Math.pow((x21 - x22), 2)) + (Math.pow((y21 - 
        y22), 2)));
        double b2 = Math.sqrt((Math.pow((x22 - x23), 2)) + (Math.pow((y22 - 
        y23), 2))); 
        double c2 = Math.sqrt((Math.pow((x23 - x21), 2)) + (Math.pow((y23 - 
        y21), 2)));

        System.out.println ("The first triangle is (" + x11 + ", " + y11 + ") (" 
        + x12 + ", " + y12 + ") (" + x13 + ", " + y13 + ").");
        System.out.println ("The lengths are " + a1 + "," + b1 + "," + c1 + 
        ".");
        System.out.println ("The second triangle is (" + x21 + ", " + y21 + ") 
        (" + x22 + ", " + y22 + ") (" + x23 + ", " + y23 + ").");
        System.out.println ("The lengths are " + a2 + "," + b2 + "," + c1 + 
        ".");
        // if else chain that compares distances between vertices to calculate 
        if the triangles are congruent on not and outputs the result to the user
        if      (a1 == a2 && b1 == b2 && c1 == c2)
        {
            System.out.println ("The triangles are congruent");
        }
        else if (a1 == a2 && b1 == c2 && c1 == b2) 
        {
            System.out.println ("The triangles are congruent");
        }
        else if (a1 == b2 && b1 == c2 && c1 == a2)
        {
            System.out.println ("The triangles are congruent");
        }
        else if (a1 == b2 && b1 == a2 && c1 == c2)
        {
            System.out.println ("The triangles are congruent");
        }
        else if (a1 == c2 && b1 == b2 && c1 == a2)
        {
            System.out.println ("The triangles are congruent");
        }
        else if (a1 == c2 && b1 == a2 && c1 == b2)
        {
            System.out.println ("The triangles are congruent");
        }
        else
            System.out.println ("The triangles are not congruent");
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Comparing double values with `==` is unlikely to yield useful results, due to the inexact nature of IEEE floating-point types.  Instead, check if two double values are “nearly equal” by checking the magnitude of their difference.

Comment: Elaborating upon what @VGR said, imagine you have a physical ruler that you're measuring the sides with. Even if you measure two sides that are equal, you're never going to get exactly the same result—the same applies to functions that deal with floating-point types such as `Math.sqrt()`. It would only take one tiny imprecision to stop `==` from returning true when it should. Instead, as VGR suggested, use something like `Math.abs(b1-a2) < 0.0001` in place of `b1 == a2`. (VGR, correct me if there's a better way of doing that.)

Comment: If you are not allowed to use loops (per instructions) then there is no way for you to write this code more efficiently -- meaning a shorter version with significantly fewer lines of code.

Comment: What about the formatting? Is it ok? also what exactly does the < 0.0001 do? I dont see it mentiond in the function's description when googling it...I assume it means that differences beyond are ignored? also the way i wrote it seems to give proper results even when it deals with distances that have many characters after the 0. say when dealing with distances between (1,1) and (2,2).